# What form of English do we use for grammar and spelling edits?

Tags: discussion

Which version of English grammar and spellings do we use for edits on this community American-English or British-English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would stick with whatever the original poster used. If it's ambiguous (they never mention any telltale words like `color` vs `colour`) then use whichever is most natural for you.

I think we can assume that our readers are smart enough to figure out the meaning in either dialect, and I trust everyone making edits is smart enough to make the mental context-switch where necessary.
Editing posts for ideological correctness in the language schism would just be too much trouble.